# Can anyone give me some examples of this rule of inference

Tags: logic, education

This is the rule, and I'm not sure about the case yet. I would like to see some text examples.

$p \lor q$

$p\rightarrow r$

$q \rightarrow r$

---

$r$

Comment: p="I will study for my exam", q="I will cheat on my exam", r="I will pass my exam"

Comment: Thank you!  Interesting, what is the english name of this case? I'm Kinda lost.

Comment: Usually such names are latin. Not sure if this one has a name.

Comment: It seems like a special case of [Constructive Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dilemma).

Comment: @player3236 Yeah, good find... special case with $Q=S$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already finished my report. :) this site is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You are given:

1. the sky is red or the ocean is yellow
2. if the sky is red then crocodiles are mammals
3. if the ocean is yellow then crocodiles are mammals

From these three you conclude that **crocodiles are mammals**

Makes sense?

Comment: Even though downvoted this is a perfectly valid inference :)

Comment: I see the logic but teacher is prolly going to slap me if I send this hahaha.